# is this an example of the oxford comma? if not, why?

Tags: punctuation, commas

"I'm a self-employed, nerdy queer girl."

Is that an oxford comma that's omitted, or something else entirely? If it's something else that's omitted, what is it? Why doesn't the oxford comma apply?

Comment: Just for info: 1. This appears to be a quotation from http://www.okcupid.com/profile?a=1120076709&t=103&c=112&u=sarahhhbutts; 2. The "oxford comma" reference apparently comes from http://www.todaysbee.com/3154000000/personals-W-seeking-W/YLTJenCj3Ax0qwWbC9z6xA.html

Answer (score 3):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serial-comma?q=oxford+comma), the serial comma precedes the word *and* or the word *or*. Since neither word appear in that description, then it is not the serial comma that has been ommited.

I do think there should be a comma, however, between *nerdy* and *queer*, as that is the usual way to list coördinate adjectives. You can tell that these are coördinate adjectives because they can be rearranged:

> I'm a nerdy, self-employed, queer girl.

or

> I'm a queer, nerdy, self-employed girl.

To me those carry pretty much the same meaning.

It is possible that these are cumulative adjectives, if you see *queer girl* as a single unit, or *nerdy queer girl* as a single unit. You would have to ask the person describing themselves to be sure.

See this [Grammar Girl article](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-adjectives?page=all) for more information.

Comment: And avoid nerdy queer girl.

Comment: And avoid queer, if you meant strange.

Comment: Without the comma (and more context), I would assume that this is a girl who identifies as queer, rather than one who is describing herself as being a bit odd.

Comment: @mplungjan It's what she styles herself – maezr's quoting. And apparently, Janus is right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If I’d avoided all the nerdy queer girls I came across in this life, I’d’ve had a lot fewer friends, I tell ya. :)